# c++; how would i return a given element in an array without bracket notation?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

How would i point to the second element w/o doing numbers[1] ?

```
int numbers[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Comment: `numbers[1]` is the same as `*(numbers + 1)`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You said without doing `numbers[1]`. Why don't you spice it up and do `1[numbers]`? :P Other than that, `*(numbers + 1)` and `*(1 + numbers)` are all I can really think of without getting into obfuscated code.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @chris Damn, I thought I could be the first one to come up with this syntax craziness ;)

Comment: Has to be my favourite way of confusing newer people to C++.

Comment: Mine is the trigraph-y `numbers??(1??)` :-)

Comment: Don't forget digraphs. They're more fun since they're mandatory for C99 and don't produce warnings, which trigraphs often do. In this case `numbers<:1:>`.

Answer (score 7):

To access 2nd element:

```
*(numbers+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with that notation there isn't any advantage and it is much less concise.

one way is to do this:

```
*(numbers+5); //fifth element
```

Or you can (preferably) use a managed array like a vector

```
std::vector<int> numbers {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
numbers.at(3); //third element -- bounds checked
```

Comment: That first access is out of bounds, it accesses the 6th element

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just don't want to use `numbers[1]`, you could also use

```
1[numbers];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways you could do this:

```
*(numbers+1)
*(1+numbers)
numbers??(1??)
*((int*)((char*)(numbers) + (sizeof(int))))
```

but here's the rub: they're all much *worse* than `numbers[1]` (especially that last monstrosity). So just use that, and no-one need get hurt :-)

If you're curious about that bizarre-looking third one, look up `trigraphs` in the standard (or google it).